# javascript link() method output in a list

Tags: javascript, loops, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a bookmarking html file for personal use. It uses the javascript "string.link()" method. The problem is it only outputs once. I'd like it to loop and collect all the links I enter.

Here's the html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bookmarks</title>
  <script>
    function toURL() {
      debugger
      var strText = document.getElementById("url_descrip").value;
      var strText1 = document.getElementById("url").value;
      var result = strText.link(strText1); // url address        
      document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML = result;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>

    <input type="text" name="Descrip" id="url_descrip" placeholder="Descrip">
    <input type="text" name="URL" id="url" placeholder="URL">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="toURL()">
  </form>
  <div>
    <ol id="itemlist"></ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Collect where? You will lose the entered data when you reload the page unless you use some storage. Anyway, try  `document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML += result + '<br/>';` to add to the page - or better use an array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to save your file somewhere and you need to be able to read it again.

For now, to just be able to show a list, you can do this

```
document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML += '<li>' + result + '</li>'
```

or something more savable:

```js
const links = [];
document.getElementById("urlForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var strText = document.getElementById("url_descrip").value;
  var strText1 = document.getElementById("url").value;
  links.push(strText.link(strText1)); // url address        
  document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML = `<li>${links.join("</li><li>")}</li>`
})
```

```html
<form id="urlForm">
  <input type="text" name="Descrip" id="url_descrip" placeholder="Descrip">
  <input type="text" name="URL" id="url" placeholder="URL">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div>
  <ol id="itemlist"></ol>
</div>
```

Comment: How is reconstructing the full list to add an item more robust?

Comment: Because the list can be saved in localstorage or on server much easier. I changed the word

Comment: In any case my code is easier to grasp than your complex oneliner

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to add this links to the `#itemlist`.
Just use

```
document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML += result + '<br />';
```

This will add the result to the already existing content of `#itemlist` and adds a line break after it to get every link in a new line.

Comment: I already commented that - also he has a link not a list entry

Comment: Seems like you was commenting while I was writing the answer, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
document.getElementById("itemlist").innerHTML = result;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("itemlist").append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {innerHTML: result}));
```